# How to convert mmyyyy text into regular date format in oracle?

Tags: oracle, date-formatting

I have column of `reporting_period` in a table which has values like this:

```
  ID | reporting_period
-----------------------
 123 |     092015
 456 |     082015
```

I want to convert this column values to a regular date like:

```
  ID | reporting_period
------------------------
 123 |    09/01/2015
 456 |    08/01/2015
```

Answer (score 2):

you need use [to_date](http://www.techonthenet.com/oracle/functions/to_date.php) function to convert your string to date 
and then [to_char](http://www.techonthenet.com/oracle/functions/to_char.php) function if you need present your date in a different from default format

```
select to_char(to_date('092015','mmyyyy'),'mm/dd/yyyy') as dt from dual

    dt
1   09/01/2015
```

Answer (score 0):

```
WITH data (ID, reporting_period) AS (
    SELECT 123, '092015' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
    SELECT 456, '082015' FROM DUAL
)
SELECT
    ID, TO_DATE(REPORTING_PERIOD, 'MMYYYY') reporting_period_date
FROM
    data
```

Answer (score 0):

```
select TO_DATE(SUBSTR(reporting_period,1,2) || '/01/' || SUBSTR(reporting_period,3,4),'MM/DD/YYYY') AS reporting_period
FROM MyTable
```

Comment: `TO_DATE(reporting_period || '/01', 'MM/YYYY/DD') AS reporting_period` is shorter